# How to pass "elementId" in barcode generator in Gridview Yii2?

Tags: php, jquery, gridview, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have gone through this:

- http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-barcode-generator-8-types/
- https://github.com/Vilochane/Yii-Barcode-Generator
- http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-barcode-generator-8-types/

But doesn't get it work. My gridView:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => new yii\data\ActiveDataProvider(['query' => $model->getLibBookMasters()]),
        'summary' => '',        
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'lbm_book_no',
            [
             'attribute' => 'lbm_barcode_no', 
             //'type' => 'raw', 
             'value'=> function($model){
            return \barcode\barcode\BarcodeGenerator::widget(
                [
                'elementId' => 'lbm_barcode_no',
                'value'=> 'lbm_barcode_no', 
                'type'=>'ean13',

                ]);},
            ], 
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

I need to pass `elementId` that do the trick but doesn't found it.
I just installed Barcode Generator and don't know how to play around with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass different `elementId`s. As your code is currently your are passing the literal `'lbm_barcode_no'` instead of the value of the `lbm_barcode_no` attribute of your models. In addition, you have to create the `div`s where the barcode is to be shown and set the `format` of the column to `raw` or `html`:

```
'columns' => [      
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

    'lbm_book_no',
    [
        'attribute' => 'lbm_barcode_no', 
        'format' => 'raw', 
        'value'=> function($model){
            return yii\helpers\Html::tag('div', '', ['id' => 'barcode-'.$model->lbm_barcode_no]).
            \barcode\barcode\BarcodeGenerator::widget([
                'elementId' => 'barcode-'.$model->lbm_barcode_no,
                'value'=> $model->lbm_barcode_no, 
                'type'=>'ean13',
            ]);
        },
    ], 
],
```

I prefixed the tags with `barcode-` to avoid collisions (you never know).

Comment: array to string conversion on concate

Comment: My assumption was that `lbm_barcode_no` is a string. Is `lbm_barcode_no` an array?

Comment: no..but it showing error on that...or may i don't know exact location.

Comment: There was an issue was with the `Html::tag` function whose second parameter should be a string not an array.

Comment: so, what i have to do now?

Comment: ouput is `<div id="barcode-dsdfd23"></div>`. showing whole div

Comment: Check the barcode type. [EAN13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Article_Number_%28EAN%29) is composed of numbers only.

Comment: sometime it composed of numbers and letters.

Comment: it also not support `type ="raw"` getting `Setting unknown property: yii\grid\DataColumn::type`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87347/discussion-between-topher-and-crazzy-skulll).